# Simple google apps workflow Form->Spreadsheet->email Manager->Update spreadsheet & Requestor

Tags: google-apps-script, workflow

I have created a Form that write to a spreadsheet.
The Apps script runs onSubmit and looks for new data and sends an email to a manager
The manager received the email with an Approve button.

I can't post the approvers response back to the spreadsheet.

When the approver selects the button the message "Script function not found: doPost"

```
var COLUMN_STATE = 4; //the number is the column # + 1  6 = column G (7th column)
var COLUMN_APROVE = 5
var STATE_APPROVED = "APPROVED";
var STATE_REJECTED = "REJECTED";
var STATE_MANAGER_EMAIL = "MANAGER_EMAIL";

var REQUEST_SPREADSHEET_ID = "0AkbHPyoRSG2DdDJpaWd1bGEzb19HY2pjVHdiQUhxNUE";

// Main tutorial function: For each row
//   - if it has recently been APPROVED or REJECTED by a manager, email the results to 

function onRequest() {
  // This is the Request Spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(REQUEST_SPREADSHEET_ID);
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  // Fetch all the data from the Request Spreadsheet
  // getRowsData was reused from Reading Spreadsheet Data using JavaScript Objects 
  var data = getRowsData(sheet);

  // For every Request
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    row.rowNumber = i + 2;
    if (!row.state) {
      // This is a new Request
      // Email the manager to request for approval.
      sendReportToManager(row);// Update the state of the Request
      sheet.getRange(row.rowNumber, COLUMN_STATE).setValue(row.state);
    } 
   }
  }


// Sends an email to a manager to request approval 
function sendReportToManager(row) {
  var subject = "ID#" + " " + row.rowNumber + " "+"Request for Time Off"
  var message ='<form action="xxxx" method="Post">' +
      "<P>" + "Request Id: " + row.rowNumber + "</P>"+ 
      "<P>" + row.username + " has requested your approval for Time Off." + "</P>"+ 
      '<input type="hidden" name="row" value="' + row.rowNumber +'" /> ' +
      '<input type="submit" value="Submit" />' +
      '</form>';
      //(Logger.log(row));
  MailApp.sendEmail(row.supervisorsEmail,subject, "", {htmlBody: message});
  row.state = STATE_MANAGER_EMAIL;
}

function doPost(e) {
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Thanks.html');
  template.name = e.parameter.name;
  template.comment = e.parameter.comment;
  template.screenshot = e.parameter.screenshot;
  return template.evaluate();
  (Logger.log(e));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL in `action="xxxx"` should be the one provided in the Publish dialog. It will end with `/exec`. You need to [publish your script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_web_apps?hl=en#deploying) as a webapp, which will give you a URL, and ensure that your `doPost()` method is invoked there.

Comment: I have published the script and have the URL in my code. the  "XXXX" is just a place holder for the Https:// .....

Comment: Did you create a new version # and republish your script after adding your doPost? I've copied your script, added an html template, and published - it works for me, so it's probably a simple issue like this.

Comment: It takes 19 seconds to load the Post page.  Can I do anything to speed up the confirmation?

Comment: I am testing with a minimal `Thanks.html`, and it's taking roughly 3 seconds. So that reduces the chance that it's the fundamentals of the webapp display that are the bottleneck. You need to look at what the rest of your post operation is doing. With the editor open to the doPost, perform a confirmation from gmail, then View the Execution Transcript and look at the timestamps for each operation performed. That should point you at the slow bits. (Total execution for my minimal version is 0.028s - so the overhead of caja + infrastructure is around 3s.)